# Haskell type constraint + forall

Tags: haskell

I'm relatively new to Haskell and trying to work out how to 'encapsulate' my types in a untyped data with forall:

I don't really know if that's legal, but here is what I'm trying:

```
data Value = Value (forall a b c. (Basis a, Basis b, Basis c) => Val a b c)
data Operation = Operation (forall a. (Basis a) => Op a a)
```

I'd like to know how I could apply an Operation to a Value, given that the 'a' type of Value must match the 'a' in the Operation:

```
opApply :: Operation -> Value -> IO()
opApply (Operation g) (Value q) = app1 g q
```

Here, 'app1' warns correctly a type error.

I tried to use Constraints and type families but couldn't get over with.

Comment: Could you edit to add how `Basis`, `Op`, and `Val` defined, or mention which libraries they’re from? This existential+typeclass pattern is *usually* not what you want, so it would also be helpful to show a motivating example of how you’d like to use this, in case there’s a better fitting alternative.

Comment: Usually (if I understand what you are trying to do) you add the constraints to a function that uses the values, not the data type itself.`data Value a b c = Val a b c; data Operation a = Op a a; opApply :: Basis a => Operation a -> Value a b c -> IO ()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you don't want to do this.  If you are "encapsulating" your types in untyped data because you think the data types are an implementation detail that should be hidden from the "public `Basis` interface" of the types, or because you think it would be more convenient to write `Value` instead of `Val a b c` in type signatures, or because you have some vague sense that you'll need to deal with `Val`s and `Op`s of lots of different types in a uniform way and the right way to do this is to construct uniform, unparameterized `Value` and `Operator` types, then you're doing it wrong.

The usual correct way of expressing `opApply` in Haskell is to write something like:

```
data Val a b c = Val a b c
data Op a b = Op a b

opApply :: Op a a -> Val a b c -> IO ()
opApply = ...
```

possibly adding `Basis` constraints to the `opApply` type signature, like:

```
opApply :: (Basis a) => Op a a -> Val a b c -> IO ()
```

or maybe:

```
opApply :: (Basis a, Basis b, Basis c) => Op a a -> Val a b c -> IO ()
```

as necessary, depending on which of the types `a`, `b`, and `c` you need to perform `Basis` operations on.

The fact that the `a`, `b`, and `c` type variables are visible in the type signatures and are part of the "interface" of the types is a feature, not a bug.  That's what allows you to succinctly express the compile time constraint that the two type arguments in `Op a a` are the same type `a`, and that type must also match the `a` in `Val a b c` for the `opApply` operation to be valid.  If there's any possible way you can write your program using simple types like these, then that is how you should be writing your program.

On the other hand, if you find you need to deal with a `Val` or `Op` whose type parameters are unknown until runtime -- and this is typically only the case if you're reading input from the console or a file or some other input source and parsing it into `Val`s or `Op`s where the parser might generate a `Val Int Int Bool` for one input or a `Val String Int Double` for another input -- **then** you might want to use "existential" types, like:

```
data SomeVal = forall a b c. (Basis a, Basis b, Basis c) => SomeVal (Val a b c)
data SomeOp = forall a b. (Basis a, Basis b) => SomeOp (Op a b)
```

Note the positioning of the `forall` and constraints here: they go outside the constructor, not inside it, unlike the examples in your original question.

These `SomeVal` and `SomeOp` existential types can be used to hold `Val` and `Op` values of unspecified types that can be manipulated (only) through the `Basis` interface.  Existentials are hard to work with, so you don't want to do this unless you have to.  Code to operate on them gets really complicated, really fast.  An `opApply` that attempts to "match" an `Op a a` with a `Val a b c` through these wrappers would take the following form, assuming `Typeable` is a superclass of `Basis` (necessary to do this kind of type matching in full generality):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import Data.Typeable

class (Typeable t) => Basis t
data Val a b c = Val a b c
data Op a b = Op a b
data SomeVal = forall a b c. (Basis a, Basis b, Basis c) => SomeVal (Val a b c)
data SomeOp = forall a b. (Basis a, Basis b) => SomeOp (Op a b)

opApply :: SomeOp -> SomeVal -> IO ()
opApply (SomeOp (op :: Op a1 a2)) (SomeVal (val :: Val a3 b c))
  = case eqT @a1 @a2 of
      Just Refl -> case eqT @a1 @a3 of
        Just Refl -> print $ opApply' op val
        _ -> error "`Op a a` must match `Val a b c`"
      _ -> error "need an `Op a a`, not a general `Op a b`"
  where opApply' :: Op a a -> Val a b c -> Int
        opApply' _ _ = 42
```

Yuck.

The types you defined in your question:

```
data Value = Value (forall a b c. (Basis a, Basis b, Basis c) => Val a b c)
data Operation = Operation (forall a. (Basis a) => Op a a)
```

are rank-2 types, rather than existential types.  They are potentially useful, though they probably don't mean what you think.

If you wanted types to represent abstract `Value` or `Operation` values that could be expressed in any type with a `Basis`, so that a single, specific value:

```
v :: Value
```

represented an abstract `Val` that could be converted to a `Val Int Int Int` or a `Val Char Bool Bool` or anything else with a `Basis` instance, depending on where it was used in the code, the same way the single, specific numeric literal:

```
42
```

can be an `Int` or a `Double` or a `Word8` or anything else with a `Num` instance, depending on where it appears in a given program, *then* these rank-2 types might make sense.

In that case, `opApply` would combine an `Operator` or `Value` using caller-specified types for `a`, `b`, and `c`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

class Basis t
data Val a b c = Val a b c
data Op a b = Op a b
newtype Value = Value (forall a b c. (Basis a, Basis b, Basis c) => Val a b c)
newtype Operation = Operation (forall a. (Basis a) => Op a a)

opApply :: forall a b c. (Basis a, Basis b, Basis c) => Operation -> Value -> IO ()
opApply (Operation op) (Value val)
  = opApply' (op @a) (val @a @b @c)
  where opApply' :: Op a a -> Val a b c -> IO ()
        opApply' _ _ = putStrLn "so something"
```

In code that used `opApply`, you would need to provide a specific set of `Basis` types as arguments:

```
opApply @Int @Int @Int o v
opApply @Char @Bool @Bool o v
```

Again, a given `o :: Operator` or `v :: Value` would be type agnostic -- the caller of `opApply` could provide any valid target `Basis` types and the `o` and `v` types would have to oblige `opApply` to generate values of the requested `Basis` types.

So, these types are (1) possible and (2) possibly useful, though I'm not sure they match what you're trying to do here.